# How to add column if 2 other field is same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Let there is a table

[image]

If 2 columns `username` and `share_name` have similar rows i.e `nirdosh` and `Agriculture Development Bank Limited` then

I want to add the values of buy_rate column i.e (need output of 160+100 =260 )

Can anyone can write some sql query or php code to solve my problem.

**I really appreciate for any idea.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint: `SUM` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Ok, Thanks but how to compare 2 column have similar values or not? sql query and php code both will be ok. Can u give some hint?

Comment: `GROUP BY username, share_name` checks for similar values.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thnks. It works